# JavaEE + JBoss: Verify all deployed war files

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, jboss

my customer has a JavaEE compliant server. I send him some war-Files and corresponding checksums for deployment. Now I would like to prevent that the operators manipulate the war file before deployment.

Is there any possibility to verify the war file along the checksums on server startup? Is there a possibility to get the checksum of the current deployed war file? Is there already such a feature in e.g. a JBoss EAP?

Comment: You might want to try [Signing and Verifying JAR Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html) to accomplish this.  You can sign the WAR file as if it was a JAR file.

Comment: One of the way :

`# sha1sum TestApp.war
cb16a87d23644fb166000b4b739ef12257b77326  Test.war`

- Above value should match with below directory name under "data/content/cb" inside <EAP_HOME>:
`# ls -lart
drwxrwxr-x. 2 tmp tmp 4096 Jan  8 03:38 16a87d23644fb166000b4b739ef12257b77326`

Comment: Looking for the same feature, I saw a post on redhat support https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4201991 telling that JBOSS EAP 7 check only signed Jar, but doesn't check signed EAR and WAR. a request for enhancement had been filled but is still in progress.

Answer (score 0):

A managed deployment (war/ear/jar) is hashed on deployment : this hash is accessible through the jboss-cli:

```
/deployment=helloworld-mdb.war:read-resource(include-runtime) {
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "content" => [{"hash" => bytes {
            0xd1, 0xa1, 0x0a, 0xb1, 0x0a, 0xe5, 0xd9, 0xeb,
            0x9d, 0x86, 0xba, 0x66, 0x8e, 0x24, 0x14, 0xc0,
            0x13, 0x72, 0xd1, 0x1a
        }}],
        "disabled-time" => undefined,
        "disabled-timestamp" => undefined,
        "enabled" => true,
        "enabled-time" => 1546534691069L,
        "enabled-timestamp" => "2019-01-03 17:58:11,069 CET",
        "managed" => true,
        "name" => "helloworld-mdb.war",
        "owner" => undefined,
        "persistent" => true,
        "runtime-name" => "helloworld-mdb.war",
        "status" => "OK",
        "subdeployment" => undefined,
        "subsystem" => {
            "messaging-activemq" => undefined,
            "undertow" => undefined,
            "ejb3" => undefined,
            "logging" => undefined
        }
    } }
```

You can see the 'hash' in bytes

Comment: One of the way :

`# sha1sum TestApp.war
cb16a87d23644fb166000b4b739ef12257b77326  Test.war`

- Above value should match with below directory name under "data/content/cb" inside <EAP_HOME>:
`# ls -lart
drwxrwxr-x. 2 tmp tmp 4096 Jan  8 03:38 16a87d23644fb166000b4b739ef12257b77326`